# Can anyone give some hints or point to a tutorial on how to extract just one specific piece from Boost?

Tags: boost, smart-pointers

I want to use `smart pointers` in my code but I can't figure out how to take them out from the Boost.

Can anyone give some hints on how to extract things from Boost so that they can be used individually?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See boost [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html)

smart pointer is header only so can be used directly anyway. BCP is handly if you need to redistribute parts of boost with your application/libraries

boost smart pointers has examples in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)

Comment: Thank you sir. I am going to look into this.